# Why a "ownership test" is necessary in pin_mut?

Tags: rust

From [implementation of pin_mut!](https://github.com/rust-lang/pin-utils/blob/bbc0da95799488115a49f49da542f73283626c67/src/stack_pin.rs#L19), there are

```
...
        // Move the value to ensure that it is owned
        let mut $x = $x;
...
```

Removing this code, the original `$x` is still shadowed, so the intention of moving `$x` here is to "Move the value to ensure that it is owned".

However, I wonder why this is necessary? I found the following code will fire if we can't mutablly borrow `$x`.

```
...
        let mut $x = unsafe {
            $crate::core_reexport::pin::Pin::new_unchecked(&mut $x)
        };
...
```

And the definition of this macro won't accept like `pin_mut!(&mut x)`.

So in what condition will `let mut $x = $x` fire alone?

Comment: It might be not a safety guard, but rather a convenience feature. In this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4137604c997c517369ceeb8ae4a0883) it works fine, because you pin the mutable reference, not the original object. If you however comment out the `let mut $x = $x;` line, it doesn't compile

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov So it seems to be a "mutability ensurance" rather than a "ownership ensurance"?

Comment: in some sense. I would phrase it as "when you put something through this macro, this exact thing will be pinned - object when object is passed, reference when a reference is passed, rather than object when a reference is passed"

Comment: I think the problem it's solving is that if you do it in a subscope, you don't want the `x` to ever be accessible again. For example: `let x = ...; { pin_mut!(x); ... } /* is x available here?`. I argue that without the explicit move, `x` would be available for moving, which would break the semantics of pinning, which requires that the value remain unmovable even after the pin goes out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get into trouble without the ownership transfer because you couldn't ensure that the original value is not accessible. Consider the macro that omits it (which would essentially just be obscuring an `unsafe` call):

```
use std::pin::Pin;

macro_rules! pin_mut {
    ($($x:ident),* $(,)?) => { $(
        let mut $x = unsafe {
            Pin::new_unchecked(&mut $x)
        };
    )* }
}
```

The `ident` parameter of the macro protects against shenanigans like attempting to pin `*&mut foo` (which the ownership transfer would prevent as well), however that doesn't mean that we have fully shadowed the name `$x`. This code would be allowed and shouldn't be:

```
let mut foo = Foo { ... };

{
    pin_mut!(foo);
    let _: Pin<&mut Foo> = foo;
}

// Woops we now have an unprotected Foo when its supposed to be pinned and
// thus can break the guarantees of Pin::new_unchecked
let foo_ref: &mut Foo = &mut foo;
```

See it compiling on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e2873b466422555e484a32f95aa5c6a). This scenario is mentioned in the [`Pin::new_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/struct.Pin.html) docs.