# How does a pin_mut!() macro works?

Tags: rust, macros, ownership

Reference: [Why a "ownership test" is necessary in pin_mut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73945397/why-a-ownership-test-is-necessary-in-pin-mut)

In [Rust for Rustaceans](https://nostarch.com/rust-rustaceans), [Jon Gjengset](https://thesquareplanet.com/) gave the following codes for the `pin_mut!()` macro.

> ```rust
> macro_rules! pin_mut {
>     ($var:ident) => {
>         let mut $var = $var;
>         let mut $var = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut $var) };
>     }
> }
> ```

The book claims:

> The shadowing of `$var` ensures that the caller cannot
> drop the `Pin` and continue to use the unpinned value
> (which would breach the `Pin` contract for any target type that's `!Unpin`).
> By moving the value stored
> in `$var`, the macro also ensures that the caller cannot drop the `$var` binding
> the macro declarations without also dropping the original variable.

## Question One:

#### How does the shadowing of `$var` ensures that the caller cannot 'drop' the Pin and continue to use the unpinned value?

My thoughts:

(1) I suppose it is because once the shadowed value of type `Pin<T>` is dropped, the underlying value of `T` is dropped as well, hence, once `Pin<T>` is dropped, the user can no longer use the value of `T`.

(2) And I suppose the macro works because once the `$var` is shadowed, any use of the variable `$var` will only refer to `$var` that is of type `Pin<T>` and not the underlying value of type `T`.

(3) And this suggests to me that the shadowing of `$var` makes the underlying value of type `T` 'anonymous' in a way.

## Question Two:

**Assuming** that I am right with my thoughts on Question One, then I need to have Question Two answered, like so:

#### How does the dropping of `Pin<T>` leads to the dropping of the underlying value of type `T`?

If the variable `$var` is shadowed and owns value of `Pin<T>`, it makes sense that once `$var` lifetime ends, `Pin<T>` gets dropped. But who owns the value of type `T`? `Pin<T>` doesn't own `T` because its constructor takes a 'pointer' type (e.g. `Box<T>`, `&mut T` etc). If nobody owns it, then who drops it? If a variable owns it, then why can't we somehow access it during compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very quick introduction: `Pin` is a form of contract.

A `Pin` is a *pointer* to an object that lies on a portion of memory that is guaranteed to not be moved, reallocated, invalidated. This unless the object is implementing `Unpin` trait (in that case `Pin` is just like a normal pointer, you can pretend `Pin` does not even exist).

In other simply words, once `Pin` is created, the object (`Target` of the pointer) will remain in the same memory address (stable) for its entire lifetime.

This might sound like a strange requirement, but it is fundamental in different scenarios (e.g., in `async` code where `await` can interrupt the execution and when resuming we want to be sure the memory has not been moved in the meanwhile).

---

#### Answer 1

> How does the shadowing of $var ensures that the caller cannot 'drop' the Pin and continue to use the unpinned value?

Simply because you don't have access to the underlying/pointee object anymore.

Once `Pin` is dropped, there is no way you can get back access to the shadowed variable. To be more precise, once "*pinned*" you cannot even access the underlying objected. The access to the object is exclusively made via `Pin`-pointer which acts like a "read-only" memory access (and thus you cannot invalidate the memory) unless `Unpin`.

> (1) I suppose it is because once the shadowed value of type Pin is dropped, the underlying value of T is dropped as well, hence, once Pin is dropped, the user can no longer use the value of T.

Not exactly. Once the `Pin` is dropped, the underlying value is not guaranteed to be immediately dropped. For example, as the underlying object is stack allocated, it might be dropped-deallocated on stack unwind, or in general, when block scope ends.

The idea is that when `Pin` is dropped, you cannot anyway access the underlying object, and thus you cannot alter the memory.

#### Answer 2

> How does the dropping of Pin leads to the dropping of the underlying value of type T?

As said before, dropping the `Pin` does not imply dropping the underlying value.

The object is allocated on the stack. Its lifespan is associated with the scope block. Putting on your terms, we could say the "owner" is the shadowed variable that you don't have access anymore.

Variable shadowing does not imply dropping the object.

For example:

```
struct Foo;

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo dropped");
    }
}

fn main() {
   let v = Foo;
   println!("A");
   let v = Foo;  // <--- we are shadowing previous `v`, but this does not drop existing `v`!
   println!("B");
}
```

Prints:

```
A
B
Foo dropped
Foo dropped
```

And **not**

```
A
Foo dropped
B
Foo dropped
```

([live example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=17c1a71a16082c9d87ed80677077bc0f))

Comment: Hi @biagioF, thanks for your response. I think i still dont know why the need for a macro

Because why cant i do this on the stack:
```
let x = 123;
let x = x;
let x = Pin::new_unchecked(&mut x);
```
Can't I still move x inside something that requires ownership of Pin, drops it and still not have access to x = 123? Like I think this would have the same effect as using a macro, so why use a macro?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f069c59b34a07d3d069fc52c1e4879e4

Comment: Why must a macro be used? Shown in the playground, once v is shadowed by the Pin, even after dropping v, the original value of type Foo is inaccessible.

Comment: @Jim You don't "have to". The macro is a handy way to avoid `unsafe` code. If you take at look at the `pin` macro implementation of `pin-utils` crate (https://docs.rs/pin-utils/0.1.0/src/pin_utils/stack_pin.rs.html#14) it indeed does what you did

Comment: Thank you for your response, oh so the reason is to avoid unsafe code, hence the macro, now I get it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are partially right. It is correct that the shadowing makes the original value inaccessible, but it is not true that `Pin` is responsible for its drop. The new variable (`let $var = $var`) is responsible for that.

> If a variable owns it, then why can't we somehow access it during compile time?

We cannot access the original variable, because the value is moved out of it. And we cannot use the newly declared `$var`, because it is shadowed by `let mut $var = unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&mut $var) };`. So we cannot access the owned value, only through `Pin`.